# Resizing elements in jQuery/javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

How can I re-size all elements contained inside an html table? The table is three rows and three columns each are %33 percent. If the window is re-sized by height or width I want the elements inside to re-size to fill the cells. Currently if I re-size, the cells stretch but do not shrink if I make the window smaller.

Comment: Can share your html code? how are you using percentage?

Comment: Why don't you give height and width in % for the elements as well

Comment: @sushanth I'm using Dev Express Docking Components, and some of the components do not allow for perecentages, such as the devexpress gauge control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the width and height of the elements inside the table in % or maybe try value "inherit" both of them.

Answer (score 0):

the idea is use the percent of size of your elements in relation to the cell.
   For example:
- you have a cell with 20px height and 50px width. It contains 12px text inside.
- the size of text = 60% of cell height.
- so if the cell is resized to 40px height then your font will be 24px.
- about the width of cell if the font size is 12px, that means each character will have 12px width (with monospaced fonts). You can set the width of the cell dependent on the number of characters it contains.

You have many things to consider if you want it to fit perfectly.